# Cómo personalizar la exportación en SuiteCRM

Tags: php

Soy nuevo en SuiteCRM y tengo un problema en cuanto a la exportación a Excel en SuiteCRM hasta donde yo sé se crean dos archivos en las carpetas **custom/export.php** **custom/include/export/export_utils.php**
hay una function llamada **get_field_order_mapping** la cual cuenta con dos variables **$field_order_array** organiza los campos como quiera que aparesca y la otra **$fields_to_exclude** eliminas los campos que no necesitas. 
el funciona pero el problema es que cuando selecciono mas de dos registro en el **ListView** siempre se trae un registro y pasa agrego **$fields_to_exclude** .

Answer (score -1):

Seguramente ya lo resolviste, en caso que no lo hayas hecho te comento que seguramente es que excluiste el id ya que lo utiliza posteriormente para hacer la consulta. Si le dejes el ID te va a mostrar correctamente todas las líneas que seleccionaste.

Comment: Debes de agregar codigo de ejemplo con el que el usuario pueda resolver su problematica ademas de las indicaciones dasas, es lo mas apropiado para dar una respuesta y que el usuario la implemente de forma adecuada.